# Postgres - Case - When

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to use Case / When on Postgres and getting an error:

When I try this:

`select case when 1=2 then 1/0 else 2 end;`

Although we have an error inside the first condition, everything was OK because 1 not equals 2 and the "else" part was executed.

But, when I try this:

`select case when 1=2 then ((true)::numeric)::text else 'text' end;`

I'm getting and cast error even though the condition is not true.

Anyone could tell me why ?

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on operator short-circut is tricky. Here during castingit seems it fails on different phase, than 1/0. I guess that during parsing when detected boolean -> numeric ends with error

Comment: I'm guessing you are getting bit by this [Syntax eval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL) "CASE is not a cure-all for such issues, however. One limitation of the technique illustrated above is that it does not prevent early evaluation of constant subexpressions."

Answer (score 0):

In the first case the setup passed pre-run check, and the realization that it's division by 0 came only at run-time.  Thus giving you error when 1=1 only.

In the second case it doesn't get to evaluating the condition.  The error gets caught during parsing of the setup itself.  postgres `cannot cast type boolean to numeric`.  So you get error before `1=2` gets evaluated.

Note, you can cast boolean to integer:

`select case when 1=2 then true::int::text else 'text' end;`

will work